# Drop data frames with condition contains (os.path.exists)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to drop rows with path that doesn't exist...

```
data_docs = pd.read_csv('Documents_data.csv')
data_docs.drop(data_docs[os.path.exists(str(data_docs['file path']))].index, inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, `os.path.exists` looks at the whole `str` representation of the column, not element-by-element. One way is to `apply`:

```py
exists = data_docs["file path"].apply(os.path.exists)
data_docs = data_docs[exists]
```

If you print `exists`, it will be a boolean series saying which paths exist and which do not.

```
exists = ~exists
data_docs.drop(data_docs[exists].index, inplace=True)
```

inverted `exist` to drop the one with false result,
now it will drop the files that doesn't exist.